# Simple aggregation is getting failed in javaelasticsearch 8.0+ client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have got a simple method that performs simple terms aggregation using elastic search8.0
I am able to do it using RestHighLevelClient but with ElasticsearchClient  I am getting empty buckets.

can someone please help me to resolve

```
public void aggregate(ElasticsearchClient  client) throws ElasticsearchException, IOException {
    String field = "loglevel";
    Map<String, Long> buckets = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    SearchResponse<SspDevLog> response = client.search(fn -> fn
            .aggregations("loglevel", a -> a.terms(v-> v.field(field))), SspDevLog.class);
    Map<String, Aggregate> aggrs = response.aggregations();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Aggregate> entry : aggrs.entrySet()) {
        Aggregate aggregate = entry.getValue();
        StringTermsAggregate sterms = aggregate.sterms();
        Buckets<StringTermsBucket> sbuckets = sterms.buckets();
        List<StringTermsBucket> bucArr = sbuckets.array();
        for(StringTermsBucket bucObj : bucArr) {
            buckets.put(bucObj.key(), bucObj.docCount());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(buckets);
}
```

Comment: I am new to Elastic search, using 7.17 version. And I am migrating from deprecated RestHighLevelClient. But your code example actually helped me to find proper way to extract bucket data. To get aggregations in response, you have to define aggregations in search request. In my case I have provided `mapOf<String, Aggregation>` to `SearchRequest.builder.aggregations()`.